# How to display feedback message on Site in silverstripe?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a feedback form and after submit the form data saved into data base. Now i want to display the feedback data for all users. feedback code is into mysite/code.feedbackpage.php
and feedbackpage.ss file is stored into themes/ProjectFolder/templates/Layout. Please help me out this. Any idea? How we can pulled up the data ad display the saved feedback above feedback form.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are redirecting back after the submission to the page where the form is created, you can use sessionMessage() to do this, ie if doSubmit is the action the form is sent to:

```
public function doSubmit($data, $form){
    // .. do your submission business logic
    $form->sessionMessage('Good job on submitting this form fella', 'good');
    $this->redirectBack();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this. How can i display the saved data in Admin? Please help and please provide me reference link.